# Working with Spring LDAP and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security, spring-ldap

I was tasked to implement Spring LDAP in the back-end of an application and I'm having some trouble doing so, especially with my back-end and front-end communication
On my front-end I created a function on my controller thar calls a service responsible for sending the user inputs:

Controller:

```
scope.login = function() {
   if(!$scope.validateLogin()){
      return false;
   }
   authenticationService.Login($scope.user, $scope.password, function(response) {
      if (response.authenticated) {
         console.log("success - "+response);
      } else {
         console.log("error - "+response);
      }
  });
}
```

Service:

```
this.Login = function (username, password, callback) {
   var headers = {
      authorization : "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)
   };
   var jsonData = JSON.stringify(headers);

   $http.get('http://localhost:8080/user', {headers : headers, data: jsonData})
   .success(function (response) {
       callback(response);
   })
   .error(function (response){
       callback(response);
   });
};
```

But then, when it reaches my back-end, "Principal user" comes null

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
public Principal user(Principal user) {
    return user;
}
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: just remembering that my back-end  and front-end are separated applications

Comment: Please post Spring security configuration as well. If the Principal is not populated automatically this indicates that the resource is not affected by the Spring security filters.